# I can find environment variables in my path

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, backend

```
C:\\Users\\Desktop\>pip install virtualenv
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting virtualenv
Downloading virtualenv-20.25.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib\<1,\>=0.3.7 in c:\\users\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python312\\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock\<4,\>=3.12.2 in c:\\users\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python312\\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs\<5,\>=3.9.1 in c:\\users\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python312\\site-packages (from virtualenv) (4.1.0)
Downloading virtualenv-20.25.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.8/3.8 MB 2.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed virtualenv-20.25.0

C:\\Users\\Desktop\>virtualenv env
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Installed it correctly. but it doesn't create `virtualenv env`

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the `WARNING:` over there? It's telling you what's wrong.

> WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
>
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

If you don't want [to (or can) add that directory to your `PATH` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows), you can also use (for `virtualenv`, not necessarily all packages)

```
python -m virtualenv env
```

for the same effect (since the `virtualenv.exe` wrapper calls `virtualenv.__main__`, which is what `python -m virtualenv` does).